# MongoDB no devuelve documentos en find por objeto anidado

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo un esquema en Mongoose de Productos, este esquema tiene una propiedad de Categorias de esta forma:

```
categoria: {
        required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Categoria'
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es obtenerme todos los productos de una determinada categoría enviada como parámetro.

Este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
// ==============================================================
// Obtiene todos los productos de una categoría enviada por su ID
// ==============================================================
let getProductsByCategoryId = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    Producto.find({"categoria.id": req.params.id}, '_id codigo descripcion nombre precioCosto precioVenta categoria marca estado')
        .sort({nombre: 'asc'})
        .populate('categoria', '_id nombre')
        .populate('marca', '_id nombre')
        .exec((err, productos) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'Error interno en el servidor'
                });
            }
            if (!productos) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'No se encontraron productos.'
                    }
                });
            }

            res.json({
                ok: true,
                cantidad: productos.length,
                entidadResultante: productos
            });
        })
}
```

Esto no me da ningun error al probarlo en Postman, pero lo me parece raro es que no me devuelve nada con un producto que tiene la categoría que estoy enviado como parametro. Ej:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5ba87d5b8e358888e976f"),
    "estado" : true,
    "codigo" : "CER473HEIN",
    "descripcion" : "Pack de cervezas Heineken 473ml x6 unidades.",
    "nombre" : "Cervezas Heinken 473ml.",
    "precioCosto" : 200,
    "precioVenta" : 400,
    "categoria" : ObjectId("5fa006c9e8c8633bd00dc9bf"),
    "marca" : ObjectId("5fa006e2e8c8633bd00dc9c1"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-01T03:37:43.877Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-12-01T03:37:43.877Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Si en Postman hago esta petición:

```
{{url}}/producto/categoria/5fa006c9e8c8633bd00dc9bf
```

Me devuelve true, pero que encontro 0 registros y no entiendo en que le puedo estar errando.

Tambien aclaro que en el find probe así tambien:

```
{"categoria._id": req.params.id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar por un id referenciado tu query debe ser así:

```javascript
{"categoria": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}
```

Esto es así por que primero se busca, y luego se popula el objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo una forma de solucionarlo por si alguien tiene el mismo problema (aclaro que no se porque lo anterior no funciona, si alguien me puede explicar le agradecería).

Agregue y cambie de esta forma el código:

```
let query = {categoria : req.params.id};
Producto.find(query, '_id codigo descripcion nombre precioCosto precioVenta categoria marca estado')
```